# Capture Value In Table Upper Case Or Lower case

Tags: db2, cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi

I want to

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name=petter
```

Now if there is many type of `petter` in table like  `PETTER` , `Petter` And `petter`.

Want all this three (PETTER, Petter, petter) to be considered which command is for this in cognos report studio?

Or in DB2 without using 'IN' function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [`UPPER`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000867.html) (or [`LOWER`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0002411.html), the effect should be the same):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE UPPER(name) = 'PETTER'
```

Remember, though, if you have an index on `name`, then this won't be able to use that index. You can create (at least if you're on z/OS) an index with that function. On other platforms, you can create a [generated column](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0020109.html) and create index on that.